# Java ImageIO.write return false

Tags: java, java-io, javax.imageio

I want to save a BufferedImage (named "result"):

```
boolean bres = ImageIO.write(result, ".png", new File(saveP));
```

But bres is always null.

This

```
ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames()
```

returns that:

```
jpg BMP bmp JPG jpeg wbmp png JPEG PNG WBMP GIF gif
```

I should be able to save as an png.

And the type of the BufferedImage is "2"

```
BufferedImage@137695c: type = 2 DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=ff000000 IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 720 height = 576 #Bands = 4 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0
```

Type 2 is "ARGB".

Why i can't save the BufferedImage?

EDIT: saveP = "ex000567.png"

Comment: Can you provide detail of result and saveP and change .png to png

Comment: All the Details of result are on the Object "BufferedImage@137695c"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
private static void savePNG( final BufferedImage image, final String path ){
        try {
            RenderedImage rendImage = image;
            ImageIO.write(rendImage, "PNG", new File(path));
        } catch ( IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Test this function. This one works for me.

The important change is that the second parameter to `ImageIO.write` is changed from `".png"` to `"PNG"` (lowercase `"png"` would also work), refer to the output of `ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames()` for valid names.

Comment: Format issue of image

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who experiences this issue with JPEG files, please make sure that your buffered image does not have an alpha channel. Otherwise, `com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriterSpi#canEncodeImage` will reject your image.

For example, instead of `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` use `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` or something else that does not have an alpha channel.

Comment: This was driving me crazy. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`FormateName` should be `"png"` not `".png"`